# How much memory is shared during an immutable record or object update in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

How much memory is shared between objects during an immutable record or object update in OCaml?  For example, for the records in the code:

```
type foo = {
    a : int;
    b : int;
    c : int}

let f1 = {a = 1; b=2; c=3}
let f2 = {f1 with c=4}
```

How much memory is shared between `f1` and `f2`?  Basically, do they share memory for `a` and `b`?  Similarly, for the objects in the code:

```
type ('i, 'j) lens = { get : 'j; set : 'j -> 'i }
class bar = object
    val a = 1
    method a = {
        get = a;
        set = fun a' -> {< a = a' >}
    }
    val b = 2
    method b = {
        get = b;
        set = fun b' -> {< b = b' >}
    }
    val c = 3
    method c = {
        get = c;
        set = fun c' -> {< c = c' >}
    }
end
let b1 = new bar
let b2 = b1#c.set 4
```

How much memory is shared between `b1` and `b2`?

Basically, imagine a situation where the fields `a`, `b`, and `c` are really, really big.  I'd like to do an immutable update, but I don't want to have to copy all of that memory if possible.

Comment: This is tangentially related to your question but if you are defining functional record fields, defining them with `let rec` allows to share their closure environment. This is [for example](https://github.com/dbuenzli/react/blob/d595442ef1b5c1fa2d8484c645ac3842ef84b572/src/react.ml#L1051-L1052) used in react to minimize the memory footprint of nodes, see this [comment](https://github.com/dbuenzli/react/blob/d595442ef1b5c1fa2d8484c645ac3842ef84b572/src/react.ml#L94-L97)

Comment: @DanielBünzli I'm interested in this, but don't fully understand how this works.  Does the code `type foo = {
    a : int -> int;
    b : int -> int;
    c : int -> int}
let z = 3
let f1 = {a = (fun x-> x+z); b = (fun x -> x+z+1); c = (fun x -> x+z+2)}
let f2 = {f1 with c = (fun x -> x+z+3)}
let rec f3 = {f1 with c = (fun x -> x+z+4)}`
share closures on anything?  Basically, where does the `let rec` need to be?

Comment: You won't be able to do anything with updates unless you already know the updated definition before hand but for example for `f1` if you lift the function definitions up, name them, and define them through a let rec they will all share a single closure environment that holds the value for `z`.

Comment: @DanielBünzli Alright, if I understand you correctly, something like the following works:
`type foo = {
    a : int -> int;
    b : int -> int;
    c : int -> int}
let z = 3
let rec a x = x+z
let rec b x = x+z+1
let rec c x = x+z+2
let rec d x = x+z+3
let f1 = {a ; b ; c}
let f2 = {f1 with c = d}`
Basically, `a`, `b`, and `c` are all defined outside with `let rec` and can therefore all share the same closure?  Also, why does the behavior differ from a plain `let`?

Comment: No it's `let rec a x = ... and b x = ... and c x = ...`. Note however that this is a compiler implementation detail. If you know some french you can read about different compilation tradeoffs for closures [here](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~xleroy/dea/compil/fermetures).

Comment: @DanielBünzli Great.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For records, there would be no shared memory between `f1` and `f2` since an `int` takes as much memory as a pointer. There would be shared memory if you had more complex objects instead of `int`.
For example in

```
type foo = {
  a : int list;
  b : int list;
  c : int list;
}

let f1 = {a = [1; 1; 1]; b = [2; 2; 2]; c = [3]}
let f2 = {f1 with c = [4]}
```

the lists of 1s and 2s would be shared between the two records.

It is a general rule in Ocaml that simple types (`int`, `char`, `bool`, …) are copied but complex types (`'a list`, `'a array`, …) are shared. This is why immutable data structures are good: you can easily share. But beware, data is shared even if it is mutable:

```
type foo = {x : int ref; y : int ref}
let a = {x=ref 0; y = ref 0}
let b = {a with y = ref 1}
let () = b.x := 2
```

then `a.x` equals `2`.

Comment: int ref? That's an explicit indirection to another object making the simple int a "complex type" and therefor shared. Normaly in a record you just use the mutable keyword, in which case simple types still are simple types and not shared. That actually saves memory.

Comment: I know using  `int ref` is not the right way to have mutable `int` in a record, I just wanted to give a simple example of mutable data structure (and `int ref` is the simplest mutable data structure I thought of) that is shared between records.